# R - creating a new variable within an existing data set

Tags: r, variables

I am working with a data set that contains information about the passengers of The Titanic.

In the first code chunk, I am storing the original data set 'titanic1', into a new one called titanic_age_groups. Then, I am creating a new variable child_or_adult to classify each passenger into an age group.

```
titanic_age_groups <- titanic1

titanic_age_groups %>% 
  mutate(child_or_adult = ifelse(test = age <= 9 & !is.na(age), 
                                 yes = "child", 
                                 no = "adult"))
```

Up until this point, the code works fine. Then, I am creating new variables to be able to find out the number of children that survived and the total children.
To then calculate (# of survivors children / total children). But when I try to run the next code chunk, I get this error:

```
children <- filter(titanic_age_groups, child_or_adult == 'child')
Error in filter_impl(.data, quo) : 
  Evaluation error: object 'child_or_adult' not found.


children <- filter(titanic_age_groups, child_or_adult == 'child')
children
totalC <- count(children, c('name'))
totalC
totalC <- as.numeric(totalC)
survivorsC <- filter(children, c(survived == 1))
survivorsC
totalsurvC <- count(survivorsC, c('survived'))
totalsurvC
totalsurvC <- as.numeric(totalsurvC)

childP <- (totalsurvC/totalC)
childP
```

I know the code:

```
children <- filter(titanic_age_groups, child_or_adult == 'child')
    children
    totalC <- count(children, c('name'))
    totalC
    totalC <- as.numeric(totalC)
    survivorsC <- filter(children, c(survived == 1))
    survivorsC
    totalsurvC <- count(survivorsC, c('survived'))
    totalsurvC
    totalsurvC <- as.numeric(totalsurvC)

    childP <- (totalsurvC/totalC)
    childP
```

works because I used to find out similar situations with men and women that survived. But I don't know why R is not recognizing the new variable 'child_or_adult'

Comment: Data.frames in R are immutable, when you do the %>% mutate call in the first code box, you produce a new dataset, but you don't assign it back to itself, thus not "saving" your output. The filter call refers back to the original dataset, without the child_or_adult variable.

Answer (score 0):

Your mutate call needs to be assigned back to a dataframe. Just using the pipe will not modify the data in the global environment. If you replace your first block with the following it will work fine.

```
titanic_age_groups <- titanic1

titanic_age_groups <- titanic_age_groups %>% 
  mutate(child_or_adult = ifelse(test = age <= 9 & !is.na(age), 
                                 yes = "child", 
                                 no = "adult"))
```